# How to ignore headers when merging single column of multiple CSV files?

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I need to merge a single column from multiple CSV files whilst disregarding the headers.

file 1:

```
id,backer_uid,fname,lname
123,uj2uj2,JOHN,SMITH
```

file 2:

```
id,backer_uid,fname,lname
124,uj2uh3,BRIAN,DOOLEY
```

Output:

```
JOHN
BRIAN
```

Currently, I am using:

```
/*Merge 3rd column from all csv files*/

awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $3}’ *.csv >merged.csv
```

But how do I ignore the headers?

Comment: Are the files expected to have more than one row? (excluding header) , if so what should be the output?

Comment: The merged file would contain as many rows as there where `fname`'s within the combined `fname` column of all the files. So the output should just be the names in a single column. In this case, there would be two names. John and Brian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with awk, nearly as you have already done, by adding a condition on the `FNR` (the record number per file):

```
awk -F, 'FNR > 1 {print $3}' *.csv > merged.csv
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail` and `cut`:

```
tail -q -n +2 *.csv | cut -f3 -d, > merged.csv
```

- `tail -n +2` prints all lines of files starting from line number 2
- `-q` suppresses printing of file names
- `cut -f3 -d,` extracts the third field, treating `,` as the delimiter

Comment: Thanks. To help me understand, can you explain what `+2` and `-f3` are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

try: If you have to read only 2 files.

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{print $(NF-1)}' file[12]
```

Here I am making field separator as comma and then checking if line number is greater than 1 then printing the second last field. Point to be noted here is file[12] will only read files named file1 and file2, if you have more than that files use file* then.